# List behaviour is being very weird withing a loop

Tags: python, list, backtracking

I have a list that starts as

```
value=[1,2,3]
out_list=[value]

while(i<2*len(nums)):
         
        temp_value=temp[locator]
        temp[locator]=temp[locator+1]
        temp[locator+1]=temp_value
        print(temp, end="   ")
        output_list+=[temp]
        print(output_list)
        i+=1
```

So then I look at the values that I got with temp are some normal values as seen:

```
[1, 3, 2] 
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
```

That should mean that my output_list is fine too right? No, I get this as my final output.

```
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]
[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: please provide a minimal *reproducible* example (emphasis on reproductible)

Answer (score 0):

you wanna just the list join each other, right?

like:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[3,2,1]
print (a+b)
[1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

if thats the case, remove [] from [temp]

```
output_list+=temp
```

Update:
Try this?

```
from itertools import permutations 
comb = permutations([1, 2, 3], 3)
result=[]
for i in comb: 
    result+=[list(i)]
print(result)
```

Comment: I need to to do [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]] and so on

Comment: You want all the combination from your input list [1,2,3]? see update. @Mr.JohnnyDoe

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a Backtracking solution - since you have backtracking in your tag.
This will give you all permutations of a list -> Nested list as an output.

```
def permute(nums):
    
    outputList = []
    set_ = set()
    
    def helper(l, count = 0):
        if count == len(nums):
            outputList.append(l)
        else:
            for number in nums:
                if number not in set_:
                    set_.add(number)
                    helper(l + [number], count + 1)
                    set_.remove(number)
    helper([])
    return outputList
```

`permute([1,2,3])` will yield

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: @Mr. Johnny Doe - please upvote if you find this solution useful. Any feedback would be great to hear :-)